# After Windows 8 install, windows not filling up entire widescreen monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the black borders after installing Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/495308/how-to-remove-the-black-borders-after-installing-windows-8)

My windows 8 desktop/start menu are not filling up my entire monitor (black borders around everything) even though I have the graphics driver installed and am on the highest resolution available. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which hardware do you use? (Which graphics card, which monitor?). Which driver is installed?

Comment: Can you preferably add a screenshot along with the hardware configuration?

Comment: Also, specify which hardware. Not just 'an ATI card', but 'and an AMD 5770' (or whatever model you have. I choose the 5770 as example because someone else with that card had the same problem.)

Comment: nVidia too had (has?) issues with Windows 8. I've applied three driver updates in the past month for mine.