# How to get rid of black border around Windows 8 so I can fill up the whole display?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After Windows 8 install, windows not filling up entire widescreen monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/494770/after-windows-8-install-windows-not-filling-up-entire-widescreen-monitor)

After install of Windows 8, it appears my OS is not taking advantage of the entire display resulting in a black border around the interface. I tried changing my personalization settings in Windows 8 to make sure resolution is max, which it is... I am using an ATI card, how do I fix this?

Comment: Please do not post two identical question 8 minutes apart. Instead add the information to your original post.